# Absolute Position Element causes unwanted whitespace next to the site

Tags: jquery, html, css

good evening, I've got a problem with my dropdown menu.

because I don't know how to explain my problem in understandable english, I'll start with my code, so that you can see what I'm talking about. (It' isn't displayed 100% correctly on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ktYy/), but that's no problem, the important parts are there)

My Problem is, that the last Dropdown from the Menu Link 'Über Uns' causes a whitespace on the right side of the site, if you scale the browser to a lower width than **.container Width + .subnav Width**

I'm trying to fix this for hours :/ The only two solutions which are working (but both are not good, and I can't use them), are using `display: none and inline` but than I'll lose transitions or using `right: 0` instead of `left: 0` but than my layout is ruined, because this doesn't look good at all.

I would be so grateful, if someone could help me to solve this problem.

thank you in advance

Comment: First, there is no such value as `display:hide` (see MDN for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). Also the fiddle seems to work for me. Are you referring to the space that the wide menu makes at the end?

Comment: Sry It was to late when I asked this Question, of course there's no 'display: hide' I edited the question.
Yeah, I'm referring to the space, that the last .subnav container width is making on the right side if the viewport is not big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Answer edited to fit OP's revisions:

```
ul.mainnav {
  + width: 100%;
}
```

//changed to make work on code snippet

```
div#Logo {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/280x155) no-repeat left; 
}
```

Code snippet:

```css
/* CLEARFIX */

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}

.cf {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
}

header#Header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 155px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

header#Header>.container,
footer#Footer>.container {
  width: 1140px;
  background: red;
}

div#Logo {
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
  height: 155px;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/280x155) no-repeat left;
}

div#Logo>a {
  display: block;
  margin: 34px 0 0 0;
  width: 217px;
  height: 87px;
}

div#Logo>a:hover {
  padding: 0;
}

nav#MainNav {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 860px;
  height: 155px;
}

nav#MainNav a {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
}

nav#MainNav li {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* mainnav */

ul.mainnav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 43px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 70px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.mainnav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 69px;
  line-height: 69px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

ul.mainnav>li>a {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #212121;
}

ul.mainnav>li:last-of-type {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.mainnav>li:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1d85c1;
  background: #1d85c1;
}

ul.mainnav>li:hover a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

ul.mainnav>li:hover ul.subnav {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 69px;
  left: 0;
}


/*
li.last-menu-item:hover ul.subnav {
 right: 0 !important;
 left: auto !important;
}
*/


/* subnav */

ul.subnav {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 69px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 245px;
  list-style: none;
  background: #1d85c1;
}


/*
li.last-menu-item > ul.subnav {
 right: 10px !important;
 left: auto !important;
}
*/

ul.subnav .fa {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  line-height: 40px !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}

ul.subnav>li {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 40px;
}

ul.subnav>li>a {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

ul.subnav>li:hover {
  width: 265px;
  background: #0d2839;
}

ul.subnav>li:hover ul.subsubnav {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 265px;
}
```

```html
<header id="Header">
  <div class="container cf">
    <div id="Logo">
      <a href="/" title="Name">Name</a>
    </div>
    <nav id="MainNav">
      <ul class="mainnav cf">

        <li class="current">
          <a href="/" class="no-transition">Aktuelles</a>


          <ul class="subnav">

            <li class="link">
              <a href="/home/neuigkeiten/">Neuigkeiten <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

            </li>

            <li class="link">
              <a href="/home/events/">Events <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

            </li>

            <li class="link">
              <a href="/home/verkaufspferde/">Verkaufspferde <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

            </li>

          </ul>


        </li>

        <li class="link">
          <a href="/polosport/" class="no-transition">Polosport</a>


          <ul class="subnav">

            <li class="link">
              <a href="/polosport/poloschule/">Poloschule <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

            </li>

            <li class="link">
              <a href="/polosport/poloturniere/">Poloturniere <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

            </li>

            <li class="link">
              <a href="/polosport/was-ist-polo/">Was ist Polo <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

            </li>

            <li class="link">
              <a href="/polosport/das-regelwerk/">Das Regelwerk <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

            </li>

          </ul>


        </li>

        <li class="link">
          <a href="/dressage/" class="no-transition">Dressage</a>



        </li>

        <li class="link">
          <a href="/die-anlage/" class="no-transition">Die Anlage</a>


          <ul class="subnav">

            <li class="link">
              <a href="/die-anlage/bildergalerie/">Bildergalerie <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

            </li>

          </ul>


        </li>

        <li class="link">
          <a href="/unterricht/" class="no-transition">Unterricht</a>



        </li>

        <li class="link last-menu-item">
          <a href="/ueber-uns/" class="no-transition">Über Uns</a>


          <ul class="subnav">

            <li class="link">
              <a href="/ueber-uns/das-team/">Das Team <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>

            </li>

          </ul>


        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I think that wont work.
.container can't have a width of 100% because it needs to be centered in the middle of header and it must have a width of 1140px; Also width leaving out the float left, the logo isn't anymore displayed next to the mainnav.

Comment: So the important parts aren't in your fiddle. If you have extremely specific needs. Then you need to spell them out before people try and solve your question.

Comment: There's everything in the fiddle. The only thing which isn't, is the logo image

Comment: no sry :/ Still not. I think that's because the container of the dropdown is there and this one goes out of my wrapper.

Comment: I guess I have no idea what your problem is then, sry. unless you make a screenshot of the desired outcome and your current problem with the way the fiddle renders I cannot help anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This does fix the spacing issue, though now you will need to adjust the submenu to fly out to the left rather than the right. But not a big deal. I did a little to fix that for you, so you're halfway there.

The problem is that the browser still allows space for 'hidden' elements. If you want to remove it from space calculations you need to use `display:none`

```
li.last-menu-item > ul.subnav { display: none; }
li.last-menu-item:hover > ul.subnav { display: block; width: auto; }
```

Alternate solution, since I saw you didn't like `display:none`.  I think this solution is a bit more elegant anyhow:

```
ul.mainnav > li.last-menu-item ul.subnav {
    left: initial;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I _can_ read. You said you don't like `display: none`. OK, well then you'll need to set it to the left and move it over when you're ready for it.  Let me see what I can cook up quickly.

Comment: Though, I'm not seeing any transitions in this Fiddle. What transitions are you talking about losing?

Comment: I think the key part here is the `left: initial` statement in addition to `right: 0px`.  See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8qQfT/

Comment: hi, the transitions are not in the fiddle, thought they weren't important in the code. Yeah I know, that  it would solve the problem if the last menu goes to the left. but that didn't look good. so that's no option :/

Comment: If the transitions are a consideration in your answer then they are relevant. And, you can make the space go away, but then the flyout displays off-screen if it goes to the right. So not sure that looks good either...certainly not usable. :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think the only way solving this is it when the last dropdown goes left and not right. I don't like it but ok. I'm using mediaqueries, so that the menu only goes left if the screen is not big enough.

at first add a class to the last menu item

```
$('.mainnav > li').last().addClass('last-menu-item');
```

and here's the css

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1412px) {

li.last-menu-item:hover ul.subnav {
    right: 0 !important;
    left: auto !important;
}

li.last-menu-item > ul.subnav {
    right: 10px !important;
    left: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Use `!important` sparingly. You don't have to use them if your selector is more specific or comes later in the CSS.  So, if you put your `:hover` declaration last, it will override the non-`:hover` one.  As well, `li.last-menu-item > ul.subnav` will override `li > ul.subnav`.  I also found through experimentation that setting `left` to `initial` performed better than `auto`. So, the answer you've submitted here is pretty much my answer. :P I spent a fair amount of work to help you, please don't accept your own answer ;)

Comment: Yeah but that's what I already had before asking this question. I just won't to use it, because I hoped that there's a better solution. What is the advantage of 'initial'